# Change FormFunction button color

Tags: cloud-deploy, form-building

Simple question. How can I change the `FormFunction` submit button color? It's possible to do that?

I didn't find any way to do that in the documentation.

The close I got was using `PageTheme` option, but there are just 4 pre-defined options.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inspect elements of interest and add css with `EmbeddedHTML`:

```
CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[{
      EmbeddedHTML["<style> .btn.btn-primary.form-submit{background: #000080;}</style>"],
      "first" -> "String", 
      "second" -> "Number"
    }, 
    f
  ], 
  Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Tks @Kuba! I used `"<style> .btn.btn-primary.form-submit{background: #5bb85b;border: #5bb85b}</style>"` to changer border too.